# Почему две одинаковые математические операции в двух языках возвращают разное значение?

Tags: c#, c++, инкремент

C#:

```
int a = 3;
Console.WriteLine(++a * --a);
```

```
12
```

C++:

```
int a = 3;
std::cout << ++a * --a << std::endl;
```

```
9
```

Comment: В строгом смысле это не математические операции.

Comment: В С++ неопределенное поведение.

Comment: @VTT, как это понять?

Comment: Не смотря на то, что в языках строго прописан порядок действий, большинство компиляторов его не соблюдают. Даже для одного и того же языка. Поэтому лучше такие сложные выражения разбивать на простые для уверенности.

Comment: Так и понять - эффект выполнения этой программы на С++ не определен. Конформный компилятор даже не обязан собрать такую программу: https://godbolt.org/z/ZGNpvG

Comment: @Zealint: Именно в С++ никакого "строго прописанного порядка действий" в этом случае нет.

Comment: @Zealint, какую-то ерунду ты говоришь. В плюсах порядка нет, а все остальные языки отлично считают по своим стандартам.

Comment: @Qwertiy, дело в том, что есть строго заданный приоритет выполнения операций, из которого можно однозначно определить порядок их выполнения (просто никто этого делать не хочет, потому что не понимают как быть в случае изменения переменных в ходе раскрытия операций, хотя это нетрудно). Поэтому было введено понятие  `unsequenced`, чтобы свалить свою неспособность делать нормальные компиляторы на это понятие. Со Стандартами не так просто, мне известно несколько десятков ошибок почти во всех существующих компиляторах, и всё это - ошибки именно нарушения Стандарта не только языка, но и IEEE-754.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ничего "одинакового" в этих "операциях" нет. Это не говоря уже о том, что не стоит назвать операции с побочными эффектами "математическими".

Язык C# (или, например, Java) однозначно определяет семантику выражения `++a * --a`.

В языке С++ поведение выражения `++a * --a` не определено, ибо такое выражение содержит две неупорядоченных (unsequenced) относительно друг друга модификации одной и той же переменной `a`. То есть в языке С++ у этого выражения нет никакого конкретного результата или поведения. Как правильно заметил @VTT в комментариях, одним из допустимых проявлений неопределенного поведения является отказ компилятора компилировать такой код.